# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/annotations/Beta

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to build my project gradle throws the error "Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/annotations/Beta"

app-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blackhole.musicmash"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.8.1@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.7'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev29-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my project level build.gradle:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I read one answer specifying guava. But I didn't include that dependency. So what could be wrong here?
**Edit**: When I try remove com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4 the error disappears. I need that lib can anyone help?

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: While building gradle throws the error "Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/annotations/Beta". @ganero

Comment: try to remove or comment your dependencies one by one and try to rebuild. starting from the recent add on or external library you use.

Comment: Thanks @ganero The problem is with com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4. But how to resolve?

Comment: You should find that multiple dependencies are listed in the error message itself. Both those dependencies include the `Beta` class which is why it's failing. For me, I found it was because I had two guava versions, one of which was a legacy old version that was still in my build folder, so I just needed to do a Gradle clean. Your situation is likely more complex....

Comment: ....You may find that you have two existing dependencies which include Gradle as a transitive dependency (check your "Project -> External Libraries" view in Android Studio, and also binaries directly included). You can exclude Gradle if needed like this: `implementation('...') {exclude module: 'guava'}` Good luck.